# Extract a column value from one tab from on the key and assign it in to other tab value using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have an excel generated report that has the input tab which has the following values in the column A

- paramStartDate

  - paramEndDate
  - format
  - networkSelected

Please refer to the attached jpeg as below
[image]

**However please note that order in column A is not fixed .**

Now I have to populate Report tab in the same generated excel(plz refer to attached second image as below
[image]

so that

Network in **column A of Report Tab gets the value of networkSelected** from input tab.

**Start Date in Column A of Report Tab gets the value of paramStartDate** from input tab.

**End Date in the Column A of Report Tab gets the value of paramEndDate** from input tab.

**Please suggest a suitable excel formula**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do it is to use a `VLOOKUP`

In the Cell to the right of **Network** (I assume this blank cell to the right to be **B2** and your Input tab's name to be Inputsheet), try the formula

```
=VLOOKUP("networkSelected",InputSheet!$A$1:$B$8, 2,FALSE)
```

and so on for the other values.

That way, independently of the order (since the `FALSE` parameter in `VLOOKUP` does an exact search), you'll get your result.